# Jersey client log HTTP version used

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client

Testing out connection reuse with http1.1 and http1.0 keep-alive on a service over HTTPS using the jersey client.
I have logging enabled on the jersey client:

`Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig().register( LoggingFilter.class));`

Also have SSL debugging enabled using the property option:
`-Djavax.net.debug=ssl`

This gives quite a lot of info, but jersey doesn't log the HTTP version used (i.e. if it's actually using HTTP1.0 or HTTP1.1). Is there some way to get this logged out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I changed the javax.net.debug JVM option to 'all' the debug output included the data as well - including what version of HTTP was used in the requests:

`-Djavax.net.debug=all`

The output was not very pretty, but it worked.